The physics professor says: "I need to get big coat." instead of "...a big coat"? Why do you think he removes the article?
A famous professor is answering questions about solar system and planets. One question is : If you could go anywhere in the solar system, where would you go? He answers and at one point he says:

.....I’d love to do that. But I’d put a big coat on and and come back quickly. I’m going to Triton. I need to get big coat! Questions about Solar System (see: 2:52-2:59)

In the first usage, he says "...a big coat....", which is OK, buth then in the second usage which is almost followed by the first one, he removes the article "a" and says "...big coat.." (I checked subtitles, too, (not automatic subtitles).
What might the reason removing the article "a" in the second usage of the exactly the same noun.?

It's a bit of Lancashire dialect.  In some contexts, in this dialect, articles can be reduced in pronunciation to the point that they vanish.
There's no grammar point to be studied here, and it is unlikely that you'd want to emulate this local dialect specifically.

Cox has a Mancunian/Lancastrian accent, but here he emphasises it as a joke. It's an example of "bathos", combining something sophisticated (talking about a trip to Triton) with something low (a lower class Mancunian wanting their big coat)

Only the definite article can be elided, not the indefinite. The omitted word is the, not a.

reet wi' thee lad,
